# vim auto-align end of line comments in insert mode

Tags: vim, text-alignment, tabular

I wan't to auto-align end of line comments with vim.

I've the following code snippet:

```
" This is a block
" with some comments
require 'some important lib' " important lib
require 'another lib' " another lib
require 'lib' "lib
```

This is ugly. So I've the following function (in .vimrc)

```
inoremap <silent> " "<Esc>:call <SID>ealigneolcomment()<CR>a
function! s:ealigneolcomment()
  let p = '^.\+"\s.*$'
  if exists(':Tabularize') && getline('.') =~# '^.\+"' && (getline(line('.')-1) =~# p || getline(line('.')+1) =~# p)
    let column = strlen(substitute(getline('.')[0:col('.')],'[^"]','','g'))
    let position = strlen(matchstr(getline('.')[0:col('.')],'.*"\s*\zs.*'))
    Tabularize/"/l1
    normal! 0
    call search(repeat('[^"]*"',column).'\s\{-\}'.repeat('.',position),'ce',line('.'))
  endif
endfunction
```

It simply runs `:Tabularize/"/l1` at the current cursor position when I hit `"`. The result is this:

```
                             " This is a block
                             " with some comments
require 'some important lib' " important lib
require 'another lib'        " another lib
require 'lib'                " lib
```

Instead I want to have this result:

```
" This is a block
" with some comments
require 'some important lib' " important lib
require 'another lib'        " another lib
require 'lib'                " lib
```

Basically I just want to align the end of line comments. The block comments should be leaved untouched. Is there a way in calling [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) to get the desired result? Or just another vim plugin?

Comment: What distinguishes and end of line comment from a block comment? `Tabularize /[^"].*\zs"/l1` might work. Assuming all block comments start in the first column.

Comment: @FDinoff Your assumtion is right (block comments will start in the first column). This seems to work. Thank you